# Socket.Send/ReceiveTimeout is not working

Tags: c#, sockets, timeout

I am wondering if the timeout mechanism is working in my APP.
So I make an experiment to check and I found that the socket timeout of the following in my code not working!

1. Socket Connect timeout

   To check the timeout is working or not, my phone is not connected to the test device, the log print S4 to S5 only spends about 100-200 ms but not 2 sec.
   My imagining result: S4 -> (wait for 2 sec) -> S5.
   The actual result: S4 -> (spend 100-200 ms) -> S5.
2. Socket Send timeout

   To check the timeout is working or not, my phone is connected to the device at the beginning, then I power off the test device at Log-S6. Then I will get an exception with Log-S10 and no print Log-S7. The timeout I thought will be 4 sec but log print S7 to S10 spends about 1-6 sec randomly.
   My imagining result: S7 -> (wait for 4 sec) -> S10.
   The actual result: S7 -> (spend 1-6 sec randomly) -> S10.
3. Socket Receive timeout

   To check the timeout is working or not, my phone is connected to the device and sends the illegal command to the test device, so the test device will not respond. The timeout I thought will be 7 sec but log print S7 to S8 spends about 6-10 sec randomly.
   My imagining result: S7 -> (wait for 7 sec) -> S8.
   The actual result: S7 -> (spend 6-10 sec randomly) -> S8.

Have I missed something to be declared?
Or am I misunderstanding the meaning of each timeout setting?

```
string Log_Record = "";
public byte[] SocketConnectCommendd(string host, int portd, byte[] sendBytes)
        {
            try
            {
                Log_Record += "S1";
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(host);
                IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(ip, portd);
                Socket sk = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                sk.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, true);
                sk.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, true);

                sk.SendTimeout = 4000;
                sk.ReceiveTimeout = 7000;
                Log_Record += "S2";
                IAsyncResult result = sk.BeginConnect(ip, portd, null, null);

                Log_Record += "S3";
                bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000, true);
                Log_Record += "S4";

                if (!success)
                {
                    Log_Record += "S5";
                    sk.Close();
                    throw new ApplicationException("Failed to connect server.");
                }

                Log_Record += "S6";
                sk.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, 0);
                Log_Record += "S7";

                rcvlend = sk.Receive(buffersd, buffersd.Length, 0);
                Log_Record += "S8";
                byte[] rcvdata = new byte[rcvlend];
                for (int i = 0; i < rcvlend; i++)
                {
                    rcvdata[i] = buffersd[i];
                }

                sk.Close();
                Log_Record += "S9";
                return rcvdata;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log_Record += "S10";
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Point 1: Why should S4 -> S5 take two seconds? The 2 seconds that are specified in WaitOne is the timeout it will wait at most.
Point 2: If you turn off the device, the operating system will (sooner or later) detect that the connection is lost and thus you will get some kind of socket exception that throws you into the catch block. Also here the timeout you sepcify for receiving data is the maximum time but when the connection is gone, there is no need to wait any longer ;-)

Comment: @MarkusSafar But I set 4 sec and I got 6 sec timeout. It's not like the situation(early to response an exception) you imagined. So if I want to confirm whether these 3 timeout mechanism is working, what test method should I use?
But I set 4 sec and I got 6 sec timeout. It's not like the situation(early to response an exception) you imagined. So if I want to confirm whether these 3 timeout mechanism is working, what test method should I use?

Comment: I guess you are confusing something here. If you try to send data, the send timeout starts as soon as all data is transferred to the output buffer. If the data stays in the output buffer for the specified amount of time, then the timeout occurs. You should check the `ErrorCode` property in the exception you catched and check, what's the reason the `Send` call fails. Please post the details of your analysis here. [Windows Sockets Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) may be of help.